# Is there way to limit number of rows for each element in a IN clause?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that looks like this:

```
Select * from table1 where field1 = 4 and field2 in (2,3,4,5);
```

Let's say I want 25 rows for each element in my field2 list (100 rows all together), how can I achieve this?

Comment: either use the row_number window function in a subquery, or do a union of 4 queries each with a limit.  but if you have a limit, you should specify some order too, so which rows show up is not arbitrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a ROW_NUMBER to your query with field2 as Ppartition, you can select the number of rows you need per field.

you have to add a `ORDER BY` to the window function tio get the correct rows, but i don't know enough about your table

```
SELECT *
FROM
(Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fild2 ) rn from table1 where field1 = 4 and field2 in (2,3,4,5)) t2
WHERE rn <= 4
```

and here is a version for mysql 5.7

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 ( field1 int ,field2 int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(4,2),(4,2),(4,2),(4,2),(4,2),(4,3),(4,3),(4,3),(4,3),(4,4)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM 
> (SELECT 
> field1,
>   IF (@field2 = field2 ,@row_number :=  @row_number + 1,@row_number := 1) AS rn,
>     @field2 := field2 field2
> FROM
>     (SELECT * FROM table1 where field1 = 4 and field2 in (2,3,4,5) ORDER BY field2) t1,
>     (SELECT @field2:=0,@row_number:=0) as t ) t2
>     WHERE rn <= 4
> ```

> ```
> field1 | rn | field2
> -----: | -: | -----:
>      4 |  1 |      2
>      4 |  2 |      2
>      4 |  3 |      2
>      4 |  4 |      2
>      4 |  1 |      3
>      4 |  2 |      3
>      4 |  3 |      3
>      4 |  4 |      3
>      4 |  1 |      4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=789d8c22a4e8907dad07addee0d2f335)*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I should have been more clear, I am on MySQL 5.7.

Comment: also can you elaborate why rn <= 4? I am returning less than 4 rows for each element in field2 list?

Comment: i add added a version for mysql 5.7   4 was only a sample as you didn't provide data

Comment: Solution worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concern by this, you are having an architecture problem. The limit exists but you have to avoid it even the half, in any case the wrong consumptions of your own resources.

Several solutions to this, but the normal situation is make a temporal (USP) or definitive transactional table, put the data in them, select/join the data and drop temporal table / truncate definitive table, after use.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Can you elaborate on having an architecture problem? Thanks

Comment: can you go into a lot more detail?  it's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve or what your suggestion actually looks like